# Change state of variable defined in ng-repeat in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toggle, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'd like to know whether it's possible to change the value of a variable defined in ng-repeat from the controller or not ?

I'm trying to initialize a simple variable "opened" used for toggling in a ng-repeat, inside the controller.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="active[$index]" ng-click="active[$index]?opened=true:''" />
    <a href ng-click="opened=!opened"><span class="glyphicon" ng-class="opened ? 'glyphicon-triangle-bottom' : 'glyphicon-triangle-right'"></span></a>
{{item.title}}  
    <span ng-show="opened">{{item.title}}</span>    
</div>
```

Here is a plunker showing an example.
http://plnkr.co/edit/lebA2dokhq2W4AsbjKWB?p=preview

Thank you,

Comment: Instead of using `opened` why not use `active[$index]`?

Comment: active, is the boolean saying whether the checkbox is checked or not.
But i'd like to let the user being able to hide the content and let the checkbox checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is no, because your controller doesn't have access to that scope.

The $scope object you can access from your controller is your "root" scope. Directives like ng-repeat create their own child scopes, which "inherit" their ancestors, meaning they can access their variables. Parent scopes can't access child scopes.

However, there is a trick for that.

You have to define your variable on your root scope (on your controller) and then you can define new properties inside your ng-repeat scope.

like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="active[$index]" ng-click="active[$index]?opened=true:''" />
    <a href ng-click="option.opened=!option.opened"><span class="glyphicon" ng-class="option.opened ? 'glyphicon-triangle-bottom' : 'glyphicon-triangle-right'"></span></a>
    {{item.title}}  
    <span ng-show="option.opened">{{item.title}}</span>    
</div>
```

In your controller, make sure to create this object:
    `$scope.options = {}`

Comment: Ok thank you, so far i did: $scope.opened = []; in controller.
And opened [$index] instead of opened in my ng-repeat.

Comment: And i forgot to say that i had to initialise $scope.opened with $index values in my init method.
Not that clean tbh.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my case in that way:

Declared on js controller:

```
$scope.opened = [];
```

On the item in html put that:

```
ng-click="opened[$index].valor = (rotateImg[$index] = !rotateImg[$index])"
```

And on the img class that:

```
ng-class="opened[$index].valor ? 'rotate': ''"
```

The CSS is that:

```
.rotate {
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```